# GitHub account rename

Tags: github, rename, account

Im new at GitHub and have (by error) created an account at home and one at work, since i thought there might be problems, security issues or other by using my personal account at work. Turns out there is not :).

So i would like to delete my home account (done) and use the one i created at work only, making it my "real" account.

This means i would like to rename my work account, to the name of my former home account (which is deleted).

1. My work account have no repositories of its own yet.
2. My work have granted me access to their project and that's it.

So if i rename my work account:

1. Will i have to do anything with my local copy of the work remote (owned by some company account)
   Or
2. Should I be able to continue work as if nothing have happend?

For some reason (proberbly obvious) this is scenarie is not mentioned in the GitHub warning when trying to change account name.

Comment: I'd suggest [contacting Github support](https://github.com/contact) if to see if the rename is even possible.  If it is, yes, the existing repository URLs will be invalidated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your username via your account settings: https://github.com/settings/admin

If you forked your company's code and cloned from your fork, you will need to update your remotes. If you cloned directly from your company's repo, you should be set since you don't have any repos of your own.

If you run `git remote -v` you should see something along the lines of:

```
origin git@github.com:Account/repo.git
```

If Account is your account, it will need to be updated after you change your username. If it is your company account, no changes should be necessary.